# Inject importScript of workbox CDN script

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I use workbox and I use these settings for generating service worker.

workbox-config.json

```json
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "dist/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.js",
    "index.html"
  ],
  "swDest": "dist/sw.js",
  "swSrc": "src/sw.js"
};
```

src/sw.js

```js
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.4/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.core.skipWaiting();

workbox.core.clientsClaim();

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST, {});
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/(?:maps\/.+\.json|pwa\/.+|pois\/.+\.json|apps\/.+\.json|tmbs\/.+_menu\.jpg|img\/.+\.(?:png|jpg))$/, new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({ "cacheName":"resourcesCache", plugins: [new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({ maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: false })] }), 'GET');
```

Build command

```sh
workbox injectManifest
```

This works fine, but what I want to do is, to inject 'importScript of workbox CDN script (`importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.4/workbox-sw.js");`)' programatically.
If I hard-coded it to `src/sw.js`, I have to update this section manually once I updated workbox version.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not clear on what you're asking. What does injecting importScript programmatically mean? If you're just looking to add in an `importScript(...)` statement to your file programmatically, the `workbox-build` tools won't help with that, but you can use any other way of editing text files programmatically to do it.

Comment: Yes, you guessed it. I'm sorry for my poor English. And I understood that I can't do what I wanted. Thank you.